# Sitting students on a bench

Tags: combinatorics

- In a certain bench there are **x** seats: $seat_{\{0 \le i < x | i,x\in\mathbb{N}\}}$
- There are **y** students in total: $student_{\{0 \le i < y | i,y\in\mathbb{N}\}}$
- **x** students should be seated on the bench for
  $numOfDays = \lceil{y / x}\rceil$ days, such that on first day, $student_{\{0 \le i < x\}}$ will sit, on the second day $student_{\{x \le i < 2x\}}$ will sit and so on...

On the last day we may have to seat students who have already sat the day before.

For example, for $x = 3$, $y = 5$, on the first day $student_0$, $student_1$, $student_2$ will sit, and on the second day $student_2$, $student_3$, $student_4$ will sit.

Let $i$ be the index of the current day ($\{0 \le i\in\mathbb{N} < numOfDays\}$). Calculate the formulas of:

$min\_i$: the index of the **first** student to sit on the bench on day **i**

$max\_i$: the index of the **last** student to sit on the bench on day **i**

---

I tried to play with the data, but I kept getting tangled up with the last day. I can't find a formula that is correct for all days. I would love to get directions for a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there might be a gap in your statement, but I will give you the answer that I think is correct. To simplify notation, let $S_i$ represent the $i^\text{th}$ student and write $s_i$ for the $i^\text{th}$ seat on the bench. We want to compute the minimum $m_i$ and the maximum $M_i.$

As you have mentioned in your statement, the last day is the only one that may cause us problems. Note that because the number of days is $d = \lceil \frac{y}{x} \rceil,$ then according to the rule in the statement, on the last day we should sit students $S_{(d - 1)x}$ through $S_{d x - 1}.$ However, note that $d x - 1 = \lceil \frac{y}{x} \rceil x - 1 > y - 1.$ Thus we will indeed encounter overlaps with the students from the previous day. Also according to the same rule, on the next to last day, we should sit students $S_{(d - 2)x}$ through $S_{(d - 1)x - 1}.$ It is important to note that $(d - 1)x - 1 = \lfloor \frac{y}{x} \rfloor x - 1 \leq y - 1,$ so up until the penultimate day, we encounter no problems at all.

Thus, we have established that for all $1 \leq i < d,$ the students that will be seated on the bench on day $i$ are students $S_{(i - 1)x}$ through $S_{i x - 1}.$ Hence we also deduce that $m_i = (i - 1) x$ and $M_i = i x - 1$ for all $1 \leq i < d.$ Let us analyse the case $i = d.$ From what I managed to gather from your statement, we do not want to sit again the first students, so we are interested in sitting once again $x$ people on the bench, but also manage to sit the last student $S_{y - 1}$ and this has to be done in the natural order. We deduce that the last student that has to be seated on the last day is exactly $S_{y - 1}.$ Since we need to have $x$ people on the bench, the first one must be $S_{y - x}.$ Therefore we also get $m_d = y - x$ and $M_d = y - 1.$ Note that this also works if $y \geq x.$ If this is not the case, then $d = 1$ and we will sit all the students on the bench on the first day in the natural order, which ends this short case.

The $y = x$ case is particularly interesting and noteworthy. For example, if $x = 3 = y,$ then $d = 2$ and we will sit on both days all the students, $S_0, \, S_1$ and $S_2$ in this order exactly.

Comment: I think you meant that for $1 \le i < d$ we have no problems (note that indexes start from 0). Your calculations seem right. But, the question asked for $m_{i}$ and ${M_{i}}$ (${i}$ can be the last day as well)... I think $M_{i}$ can be retrieved by taking the minimum between what you mentioned as $M_{"i"}$ and $M_{"d"}$. Then, $m_{i}$ can be retrieved by subtracting ${x}$ (plus one?) ... Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: your original indices for the day do start at $0,$ yes, but in my answer they start from $1.$ I kept the indices for the students starting from $0,$ however. I did provide you for the minimum and maximum for the last day as well: they are $y-x$ and $y-1$ (the last student) respectively.